# Save image into subdirectory using python

Tags: python, opencv, os.walk

I want to save some images that I have processed using opencv into subdirectories. I have tried using os.walk, but it cannot save image into the subdirectories. Here I show you my code and what I want.

My Input directory and also what I want to save look like this:

```
dir_data:
 -subdir_A:
    -img_1.jpg
    -img_2.jpg
 -subdir_B:
    -img_3.jpg
    -img_4.jpg
```

The output using my code:

```
dir_A:
 -subdir_A:
    -img_1.jpg
    -img_2.jpg
    -img_3.jpg
    -img_4.jpg
 -subdir_B:
    -img_1.jpg
    -img_2.jpg
    -img_3.jpg
    -img_4.jpg
```

My code:

```py
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(output_directory):
    for file_ in files:
       full_file_path = os.path.join(root, file_)

       for i in range(image.shape[0]):
          cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(root, file_+"%03d.jpg"%i),image[i,:,:,::-1])

print("wrote %d images"%(image.shape[0]))
```

Comment: _I have tried using os.walk, but it cannot save image into the subdirectories._ Doesn't your current situation disprove that? Have you tried walking through the loops yourself?

Answer (score 0):

What's the error message you're getting?

I'd recommend that you first try saving an image manually using the complete path:

> cv2.imwrite("./dir_A/subdir_a/img1.png",image[i,:,:,::-1])

Once you verify that your image saving process works with the complete path, print out each part of the path you're creating, plus the joined path, and compare to find what's missing.

> print(root)
>
> print(file_+"%03d.jpg"%i)

My guess would be that you're missing a slash somewhere.